# Creating more pseudo-random matrices same time in R? Comparing the points sign matching?

Tags: r, matrix

I can make one pseudo-random matrix with the following :

```
nc=14
  nr=14
  set.seed(111)
  M=matrix(sample(
    c(runif(58,min=-1,max=0),runif(71, min=0,max=0),
      runif(nr*nc-129,min=0,max=+1))), nrow=nr, nc=nc)
```

The more important question: I need 1000 matrices with the same amount of negative, positive and zero values, just the location in the matrices need to be various.
I can make matrices one by one, but I want to do this task faster.

The less important question: If I have the 1000 matrices, I need to identify for every point of the matrices, that how many positive negative or zero value got there, for example:

```
MATRIX_A
     [,1]
[9,] -0,2

 MATRIX_B
     [,1]
[9,] -0,5

 MATRIX_C
     [,1]
[9,] 0,1

 MATRIX_D
     [,1]
[9,] 0,0 

MATRIX_E
     [,1]
[9,] 0,9
```

What I need:

```
FINAL_MATRIX_positive
    [,1]
[9,] (2/5*100)=40% or 0,4 or 2
```

,because from 5 matrix in this point were 2 positive value, and also need this for negative and zero values too.
If it isn't possible to do this in R, I can compare them "manually" in Excel.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are almost there!

You can try the code below, where `replicate` can make 1000 times for generating the random matrix, and `Reduce` gets the statistics of each position:

```
nc <- 14
nr <- 14
N <- 1000
lst <- replicate(
    N,
    matrix(sample(
        c(
            runif(58, min = -1, max = 0), 
            runif(71, min = 0, max = 0),
            runif(nr * nc - 129, min = 0, max = +1)
        )
    ), nrow = nr, nc = nc),
    simplify = FALSE
)

pos <- Reduce(`+`,lapply(lst,function(M) M > 0))/N
neg <- Reduce(`+`,lapply(lst,function(M) M < 0))/N
zero <- Reduce(`+`,lapply(lst,function(M) M == 0))/N
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a function for your simulation scheme:

```
my_sim <- function(n_neg = 58, n_0 = 71, n_pos = 67){
  res <- c(runif(n_neg, min=-1, max=0), 
           rep(0, n_0), 
           runif(n_pos, min=0, max=+1))
  return(sample(res))
}
```

Then, I simulate your matrices (I store them in a `list`):

```
N <- 1000
nr <- 14
nc <- nr
set.seed(111)
my_matrices <- list()
for(i in 1:N){
  my_matrices[[i]] <- matrix(my_sim(), nrow = nr, ncol = nc)
}
```

Finally, I compute the proportion of positive numbers for the position row 1 and column 9:

```
sum(sapply(my_matrices, function(x) x[1,9]) > 0)/N
# [1] 0.366
```

However, if you are interested in all the positions, these lines will do the job:

```
aux <- lapply(my_matrices, function(x) x > 0)
FINAL_MATRIX_positive <- 0
for(i in 1:N){
  FINAL_MATRIX_positive <- FINAL_MATRIX_positive + aux[[i]]
}
FINAL_MATRIX_positive <- FINAL_MATRIX_positive/N
# row 1, column 9
FINAL_MATRIX_positive[1, 9]
# [1] 0.366
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!
I have this error, if I run your simulation:
Error in N : object 'N' not found
In this case, how do I define N?